# Send push notification using UrbanAirship on Monodroid

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have an application that uses UA for receiving push notifications. I've need to add in support for sending local push notification within the app.

I've searched around and can't find any sort of example on how to send using Xamarin.Android a push notification with UA.

Does anyone know where I can find such an example or if they have an example I can use and modify?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read, UA does not directly support  local push notifications, so you would need to send the notification to the UA server, which then pushes it to the device.

Otherwise you could use "normal" notifications, inside your app using the `NotificationManager`.

Comment: Ah. That kind of defeats the objective and NM doesn't work while the app is asleep. Is there an alternative to using Push or NM for a message to be displayed while the app sleeps? (sorry if this sounds a dumb question)